# Python namespace confusion and how to re-use class variables

Tags: python, namespaces

i have following issue with the below python code:

```
templates.py
class globalSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tx_wait = 1200
        self.tx_Interval = 30

general.py
from templates import *

class testSuit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        testSuit.settings = globalSettings()
    def readMeasurements(self, filename, revision, lsv):
        testSuit.settings.tx_wait = 100
        testSuit.settings.tx_Interval = 25

test.py
import general

from templates import *

class testcase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = general.testSuit.settings
```

But this gives me:

```
    self.settings = general_main.testSuit.settings
AttributeError: type object 'testSuit' has no attribute 'settings'
```

The several imports that i do are needed for the rest of the code!

What i want to achieve is to be able to load different settings for the globalSettings class but have default values.
So, the def readMeasurements is actually reading new values if found from an excel sheet. This part is working fine!

What am i doing wrong in my coding?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're getting confused between instance and class attributes, but it's really hard to understand what you're actually trying to do so it's impossible to propose an actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the variables to be instance specific:

```
class testSuit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        testSuit.settings = globalSettings()
    def readMeasurements(self, filename, revision, lsv):
        testSuit.settings.tx_wait = 100
        testSuit.settings.tx_Interval = 25
```

Should be:

```
class testSuit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = globalSettings()
    def readMeasurements(self, filename, revision, lsv):
        self.settings.tx_wait = 100
        self.settings.tx_Interval = 25
```

Assuming you want the variables to be static instead of instance defined, you should be able to use the following:

```
class testSuit(object):
    settings = globalSettings()
    def readMeasurements(self, filename, revision, lsv):
        settings.tx_wait = 100
        settings.tx_Interval = 25
```

You can declare `settings = globalSettings()` outside of the **init** function (which isn't needed here).

With your current code you may be able to access the variables by using:

`self.settings = general.testSuit.testSuit.settings`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The last suggestion is not working with my current code! `type object 'testSuit' has no attribute 'testSuit`. How would you solve with "variables to be instance" or "variables to be static". I would like to have some kind of class with setting variables accessible from all needed classes and there def's

Comment: It sounds like you want the variable to be static (the same for all instances of that class). In which case do `settings = globalSettings()` outside of any functions, in the main body of the class itself.